# What is the origin of the deponent verbs and their evolution in Romance languages?

Tags: language-evolution, deponent-verbs, romance-languages

How deponent (and semi-deponent) verbs appeared in Latin, and why?

How did they evolve in descend languages? They seem extincts in descend languages (why?) but there are probably specific structured inherited of this atypical grammar.

I've read in Wikipedia:

> Latin also has some verbs that are active in form but passive in
>   meaning. fit (it is made, done) was used as the passive of facit (to
>   do, to make). In the perfect forms (perfect, pluperfect, and future
>   perfect), this was a compound verb just like the passive voice of
>   regular verbs (factum est, it has been done).

Why they have no name (at least the name is not mentioned in the article, and I've only heard people talking about deponent verbs.
Is it the same for them?

Edit:

Specifically about the origin (and not the other facts), I've found these related thread, with some answers about the origin:
 [How accurate is the typical definition of a deponent verb?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9064/how-accurate-is-the-typical-definition-of-a-deponent-verb) (this one, being too difficult to understand for me)

[Are Deponent Verbs a feature of the Latin Language or Means of Translation?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5510/are-deponent-verbs-a-feature-of-the-latin-language-or-means-of-translation)

Comment: An important distinction made in the first link above (the one between non-agentive deponent verbs like _mori_  or _nasci_ and agentive ones like _loqui_ and _hortari_) is crucial to understand why only the former deponent verbs, but not the latter, evolved into Romance: e.g., cf. the obvious parallelism between Lat. _**Marcus natus est**_ and It. _**Marco è nato**_. Unfortunately, as pointed out in the 1st link above, the typical definition of deponent verbs is a bit confusing since it does not make a distinction between _nasci/mori_-verbs and _loqui/hortari_-verbs.

Comment: I noticed this also è nato/est né (French), and it was the reason of my question. I think that è nato/est né evolved from the deponent structure, so there is maybe other case. It seems a remainder of the deponent structure. I would be interested to know more residual structures like this. Hence also my question about the origin.

Comment: Deponent verbs of the _loqui/hortari_-type didn't survive in Romance because of their meaning-form mismatch (agentive but passive in form). So no surprise that a deponent verb like _loqui_ was replaced by an active verb _parabolare_ in Late Latin (cf. It. _parlare_, Fr. _parler_, Cat. _parlar_) and that tr. verbs like _hortari_ were regularized/converted into non-deponent form: _hortare_. I hope that now the contents of the first link above are a bit clearer for you... but please note that the topic is not easy (see 1st link above for some relevant references that illustrate the debate).

Answer (score 7):

Most of the time, deponent verbs in Latin come from the Indo-European *middle voice*, which had [pretty much completely died out](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11258/406) by Classical Latin times. But in other Indo-European languages, such as Ancient Greek and Hittite, the middle voice is well-attested: it's a third voice next to active and passive, which usually links the subject back to itself in some way.

In Latin, as opposed to those other languages, the middle voice as a distinct *thing* died out fairly early. After that, the passive voice (descended from the PIE medio-passive) was almost always a true passive, and middle meanings were expressed by adding extra words.

However, there were some words which were only ever commonly used in the middle voice, never in the active. For example, **s-kʷ-* "follow" seems to be this way all the way back to PIE: compare Ancient Greek *ἕπομαι* (*hépomai*) and Old Irish *seichithir*, which never appear in the active voice. So in Latin, you end up with *sequor*, a form with passive morphology, but non-passive semantics. It can even take a direct object, which true passives can't do!

In Romance, this little irregularity got smoothed out: *sequor* gave way to **sequiō*, a normal verb with normal active morphology. Most other deponents changed in the same way, or died out and were replaced by non-deponents. They were an irregularity in the system, and like most irregularities, the constant and unceasing process of language evolution ironed them out over the centuries.

On the flipside:

> Latin also has some verbs that are active in form but passive in meaning.

To me, this seems just plain misleading. *Fiō* means "become", and it's not inherently passive any more than English "become" is.

Instead, *faciō* was a *suppletive verb*, just like *ferō*, *feriō*, *sum*, and others—that is, some of its forms fell out of use, and other verbs were used in their stead. In this case, it was specifically the present-system passives: instead of **clarus facier*, "I am made famous", *clarus fiō*, "I become famous".

Comment: As for your statement above that in the passage to Romance, deponent verbs "were an irregularity in the system", please see the difference discussed in comments above between _nasci_-verbs and _loqui_-verbs. In particular, note that the fate of _locutus/secutus est_ should not be mixed with the **"regular"** evolution of _natus/mortus est_ (NB: the latter fall under the set of so-called "unaccusative" verbs. Cf. It. "Marco **è nato**" vs. "Marco ha parlato". See above for the replacement of deponent _loqui_ by unergative _parabolare_ in Late Latin).

Comment: @Mitomino Good point! Feel free to post another answer with more details if you want. Otherwise I'll update this later.

Comment: As for your strong statement that "_Fiō_ means 'become', **nothing** passive about it", I disagree. In my opinion, this verb does have "passive meaning" in the sense that its argument subject is a **patient**. Note the parallelism between unaccusative verbs and passive constructions: both of them have patient subjects. This said, let me clarify that I understand what you mean but I also think that you should recognize that your statement above is "too strong" and can be misinterpreted. Cf. also It. "Gianni **è** diventato matto" ('G. became crazy'). It. BE-verbs select patient subjects.

Comment: @Mitomino Fair enough; I'll rephrase that. Mostly I mean that it's not unambiguously non-active the way deponents are unambiguously non-passive.

Comment: I'd say the notion about English is entirely misplaced. *I will gladly chat about it, but that's up to you*.

Answer (score 0):

Consentius (Keil 1855-1880v: 368.3-5): “On the other hand vapulo, ardeo, and veneo … do not have the active, but rather the passive force: for no one performs, but rather experiences who ‘gets a beating’ (vapulat) or who ‘is on fire’ (ardet) or who ‘is sold’ (venit).”

Phocas (Keil v: 430.29-32): “[The classes of verbs can be identified by means of easy reckoning. They are either …] or neuter, which signify a performance (actum), have an active form, and certainly do not change into passives; or supina, which are declined just as the activa, but have an experiential meaning, as vapulo, pendeo, and veneo.”

Victorinus (Keil vi: 198.8-10): “What is a neuter? (A verb) which ends in the letter ‘o’ and cannot take the letter ‘r’, as curro, vigilo, and domino.  How many are their meanings? Two: either it has the force of performing (active) as sedeo and curro, or of experiencing (passive) as algeo
and vapulo.”

Audax (Keil vii: 346.8-11): “What is a neuter? (A verb) which ends in the letter ‘o and does not receive the letter ‘r’, as curro and vigilo. Their meanings are two: either it has the force of performing (active) as sedeo and curro, or of experiencing (passive) as algeo and vapulo.”

Sergius (Keil iv: 502.8-10): “In the neuter itself you find the meaning either of performing (active) or experiencing (passive): of performing as curro, of experiencing as vapulo."

Comment: Could you make it more explicit what you're trying to say here? How does this answer the question?